# Any reference Iphone apps which are form driven (Data Collection and submission)?

Tags: iphone, ios

Need help developing an IPhone App which is form driven for data collection. This needs to be submitted to a classic Java Axis web service. At first glance it seemed this will be easy but i am having no luck finding good examples for the same.

Any examples or collections of them you guys can point to which address the following :

1. Form Driven UI (Validation etc.) for data collection.
2. Submits data to remote service.
3. Utilize image scanning to take pictures and parse text from the pictures?

Thanks,